# Device ID Already Used When Registering Device on Provisioning Portal?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ipod-touch, ios-provisioning

I am trying to add my iPod Touch to devices that I may use in testing my iPhone application.  However, when I attempt to add a new device for development with my iPod's identifier, I receive the following message: "This Device ID is already being used. Enter a different ID."  Yet, only my iPhone is listed under the Devices tab on the iOS Provisioning Portal, and I have never registered this device before.  How can I get the Apple Developer Website to accept my Device ID, so that I may use it for testing my app?

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: Are you getting the same response if you handle the registration through Xcode?

Comment: Sounds like a conflict somewhere - best to give them a buzz for a faster answer, or send them an email via the webform online.

Comment: I'd go with Krypton's idea, they are generally fast/helpful with provisioning stuff like this that is probably their fault anyway.

Comment: @marzapower When I plug the device into my computer, Xcode gives it the green light (saying it is connected and ready to be used by Xcode).  But, my provisioning profile does not include the device and Xcode gives an error stating so when I attempt to run my app.  Is there something else I may do within Xcode to register this device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If connecting the device to your computer gives you a green light under Xcode but you still are not able to find/add the device between the authorized ones in your provisioning portal this looks to me like a bug. You should contact Apple staff directly to ask for clarification, or eventually file a bug through Apple's online system.